# Using Gram-Schmidt to find the QR decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm having problems doing a QR decomposition of a matrix...

Let $A=\begin{bmatrix}
    {1} & {1} & {0} \\
    {0} &{1} &{1} \\
   {1} & {0} &{1} 
\end{bmatrix}$

Find the QR decomposition for A

Here's what I've been doing:

I choose this basis, $B=\left \{(1,0,1), (1,1,0), (0,1,1)\right \}$ (the columns of the matrix).

Now I use the Gram-Schmidt process (and this is where I'm having trouble)

$u_{1}=(1,0,1)$

$u_{2}=(1,1,0)$ (cuz $<(1,0,1), (1,1,0)>=0$)

$u_{3}=(0,1,1)-\frac{<(0,1,1), (1,1,0)>}{<(1,1,0), (1,1,0)>}(1,1,0)-\frac{<(0,1,1), (1,0,1)>}{<(1,0,1), (1,0,1)>}(1,0,1)=$ $(0,1,1)-1/2(1,1,0)-1/2(1,0,1)=(-1, 1/2, 1/2)$

And now I find the norm for all the three vectors:

$||u_{1}||=||u_{2}||=||u_{3}||=\sqrt{2}$

So the orthonormal basis must be $B'= \left \{(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},0,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}), (\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},0), (\frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}}, \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}, \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}})\right \}$ *(Which it isn't orthonormal)*

So $Q=\begin{bmatrix}
    {\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}} & {\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}} & {\frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}}} \\
    {0} &{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}} &{\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}} \\
   {\frac{0}{\sqrt{2}}} & {0} &{\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}} 
\end{bmatrix}$

Which $Q^{t}Q \neq I$ ($I$ being the identity matrix), so all I did was wrong...
Where's my mistake?

Comment: $\langle(1,0,1), (1,1,0)\rangle=1$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're computing $u_2$ wrongly.

I find it useful to set up a systematic way, where the information can be picked up easily.

Let $v_1$, $v_2$ and $v_3$ be the three columns of $A$.

### GS1

$u_1=v_1$

$\langle u_1,u_1\rangle=2$

### GS2

$\alpha_{12}=\dfrac{\langle u_1,v_2\rangle}{\langle u_1,u_1\rangle}=\dfrac{1}{2}$

$u_2=v_2-\alpha_{12}u_1=\begin{bmatrix}1/2\\1\\-1/2\end{bmatrix}$

$\langle u_2,u_2\rangle=\dfrac{3}{2}$

### GS3

$\alpha_{13}=\dfrac{\langle u_1,v_3\rangle}{\langle u_1,u_1\rangle}=\dfrac{1}{2}$

$\alpha_{23}=\dfrac{\langle u_2,v_3\rangle}{\langle u_2,u_2\rangle}=\dfrac{1}{3}$

$u_3=v_3-\alpha_{13}u_1-\alpha_{23}u_2=\begin{bmatrix}-2/3\\2/3\\2/3\end{bmatrix}$

$\langle u_3,u_3\rangle=\dfrac{4}{3}$

### Matrix $Q$

The matrix $Q$ has as columns the vectors $u_1$, $u_2$ and $u_3$ divided by their norms:
$$
Q=\begin{bmatrix}
1/\sqrt{2} & 1/\sqrt{6} & -1/\sqrt{3} \\
0 & 2/\sqrt{6} & 1/\sqrt{3} \\
1/\sqrt{2} & -1/\sqrt{6} & 1/\sqrt{3}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

### Matrix $R$

The matrix $R$ is obtained by multiplying each row of the upper unitriangular with the entries $\alpha_{ij}$ by the norm of the corresponding $u$ vector.
$$
R=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1/2 & 1/2 \\
0 & 1 & 1/3 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{array}{l}\cdot\sqrt{2}\\\cdot \sqrt{6}/2\\\cdot 2/\sqrt{3}\end{array}=
\begin{bmatrix}
\sqrt{2} & \sqrt{2}/2 & \sqrt{2}/2 \\
0 & \sqrt{6}/2 & \sqrt{6}/6 \\
0 & 0 & 2/\sqrt{3}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: This is very nice

Comment: You don't know how much you helped me! Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 2):

$u_1 $ is correct, your mistake is in $u_2$
\begin{equation}
 u_2 =(1,1,0) - \frac{<(1,0,1), (1,1,0)>}{<(1,0,1), (1,0,1)>}(1,0,1)
\end{equation}
which is 
\begin{equation}
 u_2 = (1,1,0) - (\frac{1}{2})(1,0,1)
 =
 \frac{1}{2}(1,1,-1)
 =
 (\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2})
\end{equation}
Now, 
\begin{equation}
 u_3 =(0,1,1) - \frac{<(1,0,1), (0,1,1)>}{<(1,0,1), (1,0,1)>}(1,0,1)
 -
 \frac{<(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2}), (0,1,1)>}{<(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2}), (\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2})>}(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2})
\end{equation}
that is
\begin{equation}
 u_3 = (0,1,1) - \frac{1}{2}(1,0,1)
 -
 \frac{0}{\frac{3}{4}}(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2})
 =
 (-\frac{1}{2},1,\frac{1}{2})
\end{equation}
This is an orthogonal basis, i.e.
\begin{equation}
 O 
 =
 \begin{bmatrix}
  u_1 & u_2 & u_3
 \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
where $O^T O $ is diagonal. To have an orthonormal one, just take (as you also mention)
\begin{align}
 l_1 &= \frac{u_1}{\Vert u_1 \Vert}\\
 l_2 &= \frac{u_2}{\Vert u_2 \Vert}\\
 l_3 &= \frac{u_3}{\Vert u_3 \Vert}
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that we have $A$ as the following matrix

$$ A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \tag{1} $$

modified Gram Schmidt is

[image]

$$ v_{1} =a_{1} \tag{2}$$

$$ r_{11} = \| v_{1} \| = \sqrt{ 2}\tag{3}$$

$$ q_{1} = \frac{v_{1}}{r_{11}}  = \langle \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} , 0 , \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \rangle \tag{4}$$

$$ r_{12} = q_{1}^{*}v_{2} \tag{5} $$
they only share one vector entry in common
$$ r_{12} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \tag{6}$$
$$ v_{2} = \langle 1 , 1, 0 \rangle -  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\langle \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} , 0 , \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \rangle \tag{7} $$

$$ v_{2} = \langle \frac{1}{2} , 1, \frac{-1}{2} \rangle \tag{8} $$

$$ r_{13} = q_{1}^{*}v_{3} \tag{9}  $$
$$ r_{13} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \tag{10}  $$

$$ v_{3} = \langle  0 , 1, 1 \rangle  - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \langle 0 , \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} , \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \rangle \tag{11} $$

$$ v_{3} = \langle  0 , 1, 1 \rangle  - \langle 0 , \frac{1}{2} , \frac{1}{2} \rangle 
 = \langle 0 , \frac{1}{2} , \frac{1}{2} \rangle \tag{12} $$
Now we repeat

$$ r_{22} = \| v_{2}\| =\sqrt{(\frac{1}{2})^{2} + 1 + (\frac{1}{2})^{2} }\tag{13}$$
$$ r_{22} = \| v_{2}\| = \frac{\sqrt{6}}{2}\tag{13}$$

$$ q_{2} = \frac{v_{2}}{r_{22} } \tag{14} $$

$$ q_{2} = \langle \frac{\frac{1}{2}}{\frac{\sqrt{6}}{2}}, \frac{1}{\frac{\sqrt{6}}{2}} ,\frac{\frac{-1}{2}}{\frac{\sqrt{6}}{2}} \rangle \tag{15} $$

$$ q_{2} = \langle \frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}, \frac{2}{\sqrt{6}} ,\frac{-1}{\sqrt{6}} \rangle \tag{16} $$

Go on from there..